# Make man pages narrow and centered in the terminal

Tags: man, less

I have a wide monitor and the terminal opened at fullscreen. I want man pages to be narrowed to, say, 100 characters wide, and centered on the screen, like in emacs olivetti mode: https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man` works the following way:

1. it uses `groff` to convert man page source files from nroff markup language to printable text;
2. it then passes `groff` output to a pager which shows it to the user. The default pager is `less`.

`groff` formats page to the width `man` says it to use. By default `man` uses the full width of the console, but we can override it using `MANWIDTH` environment variable:

```
export MANWIDTH=100
```

I found no way to instruct `groff` about an indentation, but luckily there's `less` facility called *input preprocessor* (`man less` for the details). One can provide a command to pass `less` input through. So I wrote a script which indents each line of the input:

```
$ cat $HOME/bin/olivetti
#!/bin/sh
# Define desired width of the text.
WIDTH=100
# Evaluate left indentation based on terminal width.
INDENT=$(( ( $(tput cols) - $WIDTH ) / 2 ))
# Make line of that amount of spaces.
INDENT_LINE=$( printf %${INDENT}s )
# Put it on the beginning of each line of the input file.
sed "s/^/${INDENT_LINE}/" -
```

`less` takes the command for input preprocessor from `$LESSOPEN` environment variable:

```
export LESSOPEN="|- olivetti %s"
```

`|-` is to instruct `less` to use the preprocessor as a pipe: redirect standard input to it and read standard ouput from it.

Comment: `WIDTH=100` -> `WIDTH=$MANWIDTH`. Remember to handle the case for an undefined `$MANWIDTH`. =)